# Get information about pics and video files with qt

Tags: qt

Well i have a project in which gets pics and videos from folders and also i can view them it it and when i view them i want to also see those tags kinda like the camera which took it, dimensions , the ISO, the exposure time and others for pics and camera model framerate and dimensions...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems that this question attracted off-topic software recommendation answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen anything like this in Qt. Anyway, Qt is a C++ framework, you can use whatever library you want to use. [QImageMetaData](http://www.gitorious.org/qimagemetadata) and [QMeta](http://gitorious.org/qmeta) are very near Qt style, but can only be used for images (never tried those).

Anyway, I would use the [XMP toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html). You also mentioned videos, so in that case XMP can handle both. It is very simple to use, well documented and fast (license is BSD). It is written in C++, so you can port it on whatever platform you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think Qt itself does not provide a way to extract exif data (which is what I guess you're trying to extract). You could perhaps try [QMeta](https://github.com/ollix/qmeta).  I have not used this myself, so no guarantees.